# EXCEL - IF statement with RowHeight as condition not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a long Excel database which I created running a VBA Macro I didn't originally create (thus I don't know exactly how it works). The issue is that for some reason, the VBA Macro shrinks the height of some rows, which makes the text contained inside not always 100% visible. I've already made some changes to the Excel file, so I don't really want to search for the flaw in the VBA I used,  so I wanted to write a short VBA code that would increase the height of the rows with shrinked height:

`Sub Macro1()
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer
    lastRowIndex = 15000
    For rowIndex = 7 To lastRowIndex:
        If ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight = 9.6 Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight = 10.8
        End If
    Next rowIndex
End Sub`

For some reason this code isn't executing the way I thought (it does nothing). I checked whether I used the right height value, but everything seemed fine.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Your code works fine on rows that are actually 9.6 tall. Why not try `If ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight < 10.8 Then` ?

Comment: Code is okay but I think RowHeight cannot take every value. If I enter a height of 9.6 it actually becomes 9.5. So, it  might be possible that `RowHeight = 9.6`never becomes true

Comment: Might not be the reason, but comparing floating point values in any language is [notoriously error-prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). For example, `Debug.Print 0.1 * 96` outputs `9.6`, but `Debug.Print 0.1 * 96 = 9.6` outputs `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on rows that are actually 9.6 tall. Try increasing any row that is less than 10.8 tall.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    Dim lastRowIndex As Integer
    lastRowIndex = 15000
    For rowIndex = 7 To lastRowIndex
        If ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight < 10.8 Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight = 10.8
        End If
    Next rowIndex
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot have a RoweHeight of 9.6

```
Sub TestItA()
    ActiveSheet.Rows(7).RowHeight = 9.7
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Rows(7).RowHeight
End Sub
```

According to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee50ae3f-fe87-4be5-970f-6de97a031dc4/excel-row-heights-in-fixed-increments?forum=exceldev) you can only set the height in fixed "increments", or to be more precise in "pixel"

> Although help, and the Row Height Dialog, say to set the row height in
>   points, Excel actually sets the row height in pixels.
>
> 1 pixel = 72 / 96 points= 0.75 points.
>
> That is why you can only change the row height in increments of 0.75
>   points.

Comment: fwiw, I set rows 7:15 to a rowheight of 9.6, adjusted lastRowIndex and the code ran as expected. Ran it on a surface pro.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked post it seems to depend on ppi. For me the output of the code I posted above is 9.75.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure if I knocked down my screen resolution I would have a different result. It's just not something that can be depended upon; particularly from one machine to the next.

Comment: Yes, right. Maybe the OP should try to fix his first problem _The issue is that for some reason, the VBA Macro shrinks the height of some rows_